# Why do I get 'Localizable string' in the Visual Studio editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization

I have the following `if` statement:

[image]

VS is telling me `Localizable string: "Select a Unit"`

I have looked through [Globalizing and Localizing .NET Framework Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z(v=vs.110).aspx) but still not to clear on what localization actually is.

Could someone please explain what this means?

Comment: If you ever modify your program for users in England instead of the USA, so your combobox will say "Please select a unit", then your code stops working.  Use `comboBoxFromUnits.SelectedIndex <= 0` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most likely a Resharper plugin that gives you that message. It simply tells you that a string can be moved to a resource file. No need unless you want to support multiple languages in your application.

Update: It's Resharper itself: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Localization_Inspection.html

Answer (score 0):

For simplifying localization (i.e., allowing a program to use the language of the operating system or allow the user to choose what language the application's UI users), you won't want to hard-code the UI text.

You would instead store the string as an English localized string and then point the code to load the string for the appropriate localization.

See the section about Using Resource Files on [this MSDN page on Globalization and Handling Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c08a467e(v=vs.110).aspx#Strings_Resources) for more information.